# Jenkins jobDsl failing with a ClassCastException after the upgrade of Jenkins and the plugins

Tags: jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I am using jobDsl script(which has been written by some ex colleagues) to create Folders/Jobs under it in Jenkins.
As part of the Jenkins upgrade we have updated all the plugins accordingly.

- Old Version of Jenkins(2.289.3) with jobDSL(v1.77)
- Upgraded Version of Jenkins (2.346.3) with jobDsl(v1.81)

After the upgrade my jobDsl script is failing with the following exception.

Can someone please help me in suggesting on how should i debug this issue.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject cannot be cast to class hudson.model.Job (org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject is in unnamed module of loader jenkins.util.AntClassLoader @2cd50a1b; hudson.model.Job is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader @672872e1)
    at com.atlassian.bitbucket.jenkins.internal.trigger.BitbucketWebhookTriggerImpl.start(BitbucketWebhookTriggerImpl.java:47)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.ComputedFolder.init(ComputedFolder.java:199)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.AbstractFolder.onLoad(AbstractFolder.java:545)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.ComputedFolder.onLoad(ComputedFolder.java:221)
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject.onLoad(MultiBranchProject.java:179)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject.onLoad(WorkflowMultiBranchProject.java:84)
    at hudson.model.AbstractItem$1.call(AbstractItem.java:904)
    at hudson.model.AbstractItem$1.call(AbstractItem.java:902)
    at hudson.model.Items.whileUpdatingByXml(Items.java:132)
    at hudson.model.AbstractItem.updateByXml(AbstractItem.java:902)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.JenkinsJobManagement.updateExistingItem(JenkinsJobManagement.java:482)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.JenkinsJobManagement.createOrUpdateConfig(JenkinsJobManagement.java:169)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.JobManagement$createOrUpdateConfig$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.JobManagement$createOrUpdateConfig$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.InterruptibleJobManagement.createOrUpdateConfig(InterruptibleJobManagement.groovy:35)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.JobManagement$createOrUpdateConfig$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.JobManagement$createOrUpdateConfig$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader$_extractGeneratedJobs_closure4.doCall(AbstractDslScriptLoader.groovy:204)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor385.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:264)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:420)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:436)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2151)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$163.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

I tried referring to the jobdsl apis after the upgrade under the below link.
https://your.jenkins.installation/plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/index.html
Also tried referring to different issues posted on stackoverflow, https://community.jenkins.io/.
But couldn't figure out the root cause, any help/suggestion in resolving the issue would be more helpful for me as i am not an expert with jobdsl.

Answer (score 0):

I identified that the issue is with the update i made in my jobDsl script, after the plugin upgrade.
Where i was referring incorrect trigger.

Fix:
Change the following code

triggers {
**BitbucketWebhookTriggerImpl** {
refTrigger(true)
pullRequestTrigger(false)
}
}

To

triggers {
**BitbucketWebhookMultibranchTrigger** {
refTrigger(true)
pullRequestTrigger(false)
}
}